# How to import a CSV file to localstorage using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing, import, local-storage

I have to import the data saved in a .csv file and then save this to localstorage.

I previously worked on a script to export date to .csv and now I must do the reverse.

I know I will need to do the following:

- Get the file
- Parse the file into a blob
- Save it to local storage

I have tried the following:

- Get the file
  `<input id="csv" type="file">`
  It works!
- Parse the file into a blob or object I think...
  `let csvData = [];`
  `let csvData = fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);`
  This does not work! I get a csvData undefined error when I `console.log(csvData);`.
- Save it to local storage
  `let csvData = [];`
  `localStorage.setItem("csvData", JSON.stringify(CSV_DATA));`
  It works!

What am I doing wrong or missing? Perhaps it is the the wrong type of object. I am still learning.

I did search but none of the examples are for vanilla JS.

I know the code is very disjointed. I am trying to rebuild the code from an example I found in another question on here. The code I tried to hack was designed to print the output to am HTML element and I need to go to localstorage.

This is the entire code:

```
<body>
  <p>Select local CSV File:</p>
  <input id="csv" type="file">

  <script>
  var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv"),

  readFile = function () {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
          document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
      };
      // start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
  };

let csvData = [];
let csvData = fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);

let CSV_DATA[];
localStorage.setItem("csvData", JSON.stringify(CSV_DATA));

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is this all your code? As  it is here, it's very disjointed and seems incomplete. What is `fileInput`? What is `CSV_DATA`?

Comment: I have added the rest of the embarrassing code. I was trying to hack some code I found on another question here. I thought I might learn from hacking it into what I need. Clearly a fail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You declare two variables called `csvData` and never use them.  The syntax for declaring the variable `CSV_DATA` is incorrect.  You try to use that variable, but it's only ever an empty array.  `addEventListener` doesn't return anything.  There is no element with the `id` value `'out'`.  Probably more problems... Your *first* step should definitely be to open your browser's development console and observe the errors being reported.

Comment: `addEventListener` isnt going to return your data it just sets a listener. Inside your listener you need to store `reader.result` atm you just set it to some element. Also `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated and you are more than likely wanting `readAsText` as csv are plain text files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `localStorage.setItem("csvData", JSON.stringify(CSV_DATA));` inside the readFile function.

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('csv')


const readFile = () => {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  
  reader.onload = () => {
    
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
    localStorage.setItem("csvData", JSON.stringify(reader.result));
  }

  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0])
}

fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile)
```

Comment: This is so awesome. Not just because it works, but because I think i learned where I went wrong. Thank you Zain!